# Pell's equation and binary hyperbolic forms.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory, quadratic-forms, pell-type-equations

We define the function $f:\mathbb Z_p \times \mathbb Z_p \rightarrow \mathbb Z_p$ such that   $f(x,y)=x^2-cy^2$ and $0\neq c=a^2+b^2$.
Is it true that $f$ is hyperbolic?
In other word, is there any matrix $D$ s.t $D^t F D = H$? When
$$F= 
 \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0\\
 0 & -c\\
 \end{pmatrix}   H= 
 \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0\\
 0 & -1\\
 \end{pmatrix}$$
I know that [$f$ represent all elements of $\mathbb Z_p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1172463/pells-equation-and-representation-elements-of-mathbb-z-p).

Comment: what book are you using?

Comment: @ Will jagy : i read Lam and Phister. But this question is not exist in those books!

Comment: I guess its not true. for example a=b=1 and p=5.

Comment: As with most people on this site, i recommend starting with the easier Cassels, Rational Quadratic Forms, http://store.doverpublications.com/0486466701.html  In particular, this sort of thing is in the first few pages of Cassels. If you are in a class with a professor, I still recommend Cassels to help.

Comment: @ Will Jagy : Thanks for your advices.